# Change font color to green for the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have below line in html code.

```
$('#myform #progress').html('<img src="images/ajax-complete.gif" /> Successful.')
```

i just need to change `Successful` text color to green when it is displayed. here how can i apply font color green?

Thanks!

Comment: $('#progress').css( 'color', '#00ff00' )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following in jQuery:

`$('#myform #progress').css('color':'green');`

or in CSS:

`#myform #progress{ color: green}`

also:

`$('#myform #progress').html('<img src="images/ajax-complete.gif" /> <span style="color:green">Successful</span>.')`

Answer (score 3):

You can do as this

```
$('#myform #progress')
.html('<img src="images/ajax-complete.gif" /> Successful.')
.css('color','#0f0');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myform #progress').html('<img src="images/ajax-complete.gif" /> Successful.').css({'color': '#0f0'});
```

Did not test it but it should work. If it doesn't - try swaping the css() and html() functions.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS

```
#myform, #progress
{
    color:green;
}
```

Using Javascript

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myform")
elem.style.color = "Red"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `span`.

Add this in your stylesheet:

```
span{color:green;}
```

Your Code.

```
$('#myform #progress').html('<img src="images/ajax-complete.gif" /> <span>Successful</span>.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML Code:**

```
<form id='myform'>
   <div id='progress'></div>
</form>
```

**jQuery Script Code:**

```
$("#myform #progress:contains('Successful')").css("color", "green");
```

**Ajax Code:**

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
        // Handle the beforeSend event
        $('#myform #progress').html('<img src="images/ajax-complete.gif" />Please wait..');
    },
    complete: function () {
        // Handle the complete event
        $('#myform #progress').html('<img src="images/ajax-complete.gif" />Successful.');
        $("#myform #progress:contains('Successful')").css("color", "green");
    }
    // ......
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add style on your text or paragraph, for example

```
<p style="color: green;"> GREEN TEXT </p>
```